# Google App Script Error: You do not have permission to call getActiveForm?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-forms

I am creating a script that takes information from a form and writes it to a calendar. When I run the script in the script editor it works great, takes information from the spreadsheet and creates a calendar event. However, when I fill out the forma and submit ( submit is the trigger) I get a error stating I do not have permission to call getActiveForm(). I own both form and calendar. I appreciate any ideas.

Code

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendarToUse = "testing";
  var ssUrlToUse ='https://docs.google.com/a/bay.k12.fl.us/spreadsheets
/d/1ZTDQL9G5U7RqbbKQbAfb3ERqFwpSsC3EOQxdD1zdQwA/edit#gid=441997215';

  /* Get Canalnder*/
  var calen = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarToUse);
  var cal = calen[0];
  Logger.log(cal.getName());

  /* get info from responses*/

var mySS
=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrlToUse).getActiveSheet()
  Logger.log(mySS.getName());
  var values = mySS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var response = values[values.length-1];
  var i=2;
  var desc = response[i]; 
  var loc = response[i+1];
  var start = makeGreatDate( response[i+2], response[i+4]);
  var end = makeGreatDate(response[i+3],response[i+6]);
  var title =  response[i+5];

  /* populate calendar event*/ 
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
      });


};

function makeGreatDate(date, time) {
   var day = new Date(date);
  day.setHours(time.getHours());
  day.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
  Logger.log( "The Date is"+ day);
  return day;
}
```

Comment: Your code sample does not include a call to `getActiveForm()`, please update it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm running into the same issue.  My script just took the form response and formats into an email. Similar to the OP I do not make a single call to `FormApp.getActiveForm()` anywhere in my script.

This permissions issue started immediately after I added a `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` call.

While not a full fledged solution, I was able to work around this by adding a line for just `FormApp.getActiveForm()`, saving, then saving my triggers (to check for permissions again). I was asked to confirm `Offline Access` permissions for the script.

I then removed the unneeded line and the form worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Somehow my script lost this specific permission, but adding the `FormApp.getActiveForm()` call, running it to get the permission prompt, and then removing it fixed my issue!

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the trigger from the UI and re-adding it prompted it to request a new permission, "offline access." I granted this, and it worked from then on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have change your code after adding the trigger then you need to delete the trigger and re-add it, this will alo

Comment: You seem to have posted your answer before you had finished writing it. Could you please [edit] and finish it off?

Answer (score -1):

It is very strange but your script must have a permission to Google Drive. Insert some code in the script so app will ask a permission for it (for e.g.):

```
var d = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
```

then run the script, give the permission. After that you can delete inserted line unless you copy the code from one form to another.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on a script that was attached to a spreadsheet but did something when the form that supplied that spreadsheet with data was submitted.  I found under Resources->All Triggers that I had a residual Notification with an Event listed as "From Form".  Since the script acts in the spreadsheet having a "From Form" event notification was causing the error.